# Cookie-based sessions angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

On project we use token based session, what we store in localstorage. 
Now we have to change it to cookie session. Backend is changed.
But I have some issue on frontend - after request to login in response header i see:

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=4hdlnbi5tmkfrq95f072kf2lk0; path=/; HttpOnly
```

But i can't see those cookies in browser.

Here is part of my Authentification controller. 
Maybe there're some changes what i need to make.

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {
            return $http.post(CONFIG.baseUrl + "logins", credentials)
                .then(function (result) {
                    Session.create(result.data.token, result.data.level, result.data.accessTo, credentials.remember, result.data.user);
                    return result;
                });
        };
```

Comment: When you say that you cant see it in the browser, do you mean from javascript?

Comment: from javascript. and in Chrome developer tools > Resources tab > Cookies

Comment: Ok well, the `HttpOnly` flag on the cookie will prevent client side scripts from accessing it. if you absolutely need this then you'll have to figure out how to remove the flag on the server side.

Comment: But, if i understand right, if i'll remove HttpOnly flag, i'll can read/edit/delete this cookies ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able acess the cookies and do anything that javascript permits and as a result you leave yourself open to potential XSS type attacks. Might not be much of an issue if you're not accepting unsanitized input from users or using untrusted third party libraries but its still a risk.

Comment: i think i understand. access to httponly cookies has only backend, and if after login i get info what confirm user credentials i can send him ho some state.